# How to migrate/update a Ionic1 to Ionic4 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, migrate

noob here.

I did an app on ionic, is pretty basic just images, buttons and text; the buttons are linked to another page and stuf like that, i mean there is no logic still like a loop or something.

What i was asked is to update the project of the app that is on ionic1 to ionic4 because someone that is willing to help me works with ionic4 and not ionic1.

Is there a guide for noobs to do this? i have been looking on google but nothing pop up

i read this but to a noob makes no sense https://ionicframework.com/blog/a-guide-for-migrating-to-ionic-4-0/

But the solution is kind of like this:
"Then, create a new Ionic 4 application and begin porting features over. Once the team is comfortable that the new app is stable, you can shut down the Ionic 1 app"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you use plain JS or a framework like Angular?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there isn't a straightforward guide is because an absolutely huge amount of changes were made.

Take a look at the breaking.md document on the repo, its over 1000 lines long:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md

There is a linting tool that could help you identify the main areas that you need to migrate, and if it's just a simple app like you say then it could do a lot of the work for you:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/v4-migration-tslint

Beyond that the only real way is to look at every tag and then search it and see if its listed in the breaking change. If it is then update it.

The reason why the official advice is to make a new app and port features over is that otherwise you will have a non-working app basically forever up to the last moment where it starts working. Not the best way to learn so they say start with a new working app and build bits in it that are already Ionic 4.